# Why isn't my function returning anything but is returning when I am executing in interactive mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I am executing the below mentioned code in interactive mode, it is giving the desired output. But when I am trying to execute it by calling the function, it is not returning anything. Why is it happening?

```
def alt_ele():
    mylist=list(input("Enter the elements: "))
    newlist=[int(i) for i in mylist]
    try:
        for x in range(len(newlist)):
            newlist.pop(0)
            newlist.pop()
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: You have no `return` statement. To return a value from a function you need to state `return` and value. Add `return newlist.pop()`

Comment: Please clarify the question. *what are you expecting the function to return?*. As is your function returns ``None``.  How should the input be formatted?  ``1 2 3 4`` will raise ValueError because of the spaces. ``1234`` will give ``newlist = [1, 2, 3, 4]``  If you tried to return ``newlist`` you will get an empty list. Please clarify what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to give the input as 1234 , and am expecting the output to be 1423.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `return` statement to your `function`. In `interactive` mode, when the output of `functions` aren't assigned to a variable, they are `printed`. For example:

```
>>> 3 + 5        //no variable assignment prints out the result
8
```

But if you just had a line in a `python` file that was `3 + 5`, then there would `8` would not be `printed` as you are no longer in the `interactive` mode.

This same logic applies for in a `function`. If you want the values that are `popped` from the `new_list` to be printed, you can either `print` them directly by modifying those lines to read:

```
print(new_list.pop(0))
print(new_list.pop())
```

or you could add a `return` statement at the end of the `function`.

I hope this helps, however since I do not know what you would like to `return` (e.g. a `list` or just the first `pop()`), I cannot really help with the `return` statement!

Comment: Thank You for the help. I am a noob in python. I was under the impression that pop returns value directly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @SnehasishSaha Your welcome please up-vote and accept to show your appreciation **:)**